# How can I get a C++20 forward_range from a C-string without computing its length?

Tags: c++, std-ranges

I have a C-string (`const char *`), and I want to convert it to a C++20 range (a `forward_range`) to apply some standard algorithms to it.

I don't want to use `std::string_view` because I **don't want to compute its length** (the string can be long, and I only care about the first few characters). Luckily, a `forward_range` doesn't need to know its length in advance.

How do I do this? I could write a custom iterator, but hopefully there's an easier way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I could write a custom iterator, but hopefully there's an easier way.

Instead, you can write a custom sentinel type for null-terminated byte strings

```
struct ntbs_sentinel {
  constexpr bool operator==(const char* s) const {
    return *s == '\0';
  }
};

const char* s = /* */;
std::ranges::contiguous_range auto r = std::ranges::subrange(s, ntbs_sentinel{});
```